# Set.add only add in 1 item

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

Set only adds 1 copy of an array and I'm not sure why it doesn't keep adding other copies.

The function below takes in an array of trips with the travelers id and another array containing the travelers' ids and names. In this chunk of code,

```
if(item.type === type){
      store.add(...item.travelers);
    }
```

I expected that 123,456 and 789 will be added to the set. However, only 123 and 456 are added. Why doesn't the Set add in the second copy (which would be 456 and 789)?

```
const travelers = [
  {
  id: 123,
  name: 'John'
  },
  {
  id: 456,
  name: 'Raymond'
  },
  {
  id: 789,
  name: 'Mary'
  },
];


const trip = [
  {
    type: 'car',
    travelers: [123, 456]
  },
  {
    type: 'flight',
    travelers: []
  },
  {
    type: 'car',
    travelers: [456, 789]
  },
];


function determinePeopleForEachTripType(arr, travelers, type){
  const result = [];
  let store = new Set();

  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    let item = arr[i];
    if(item.type === type){
      store.add(...item.travelers);
    }
  }

  store.forEach(eachStore =>{
    for(let j = 0; j< travelers.length; j++){
      if(eachStore === travelers[j].id){
        result.push(travelers[j].name)
      }
    }
  })

  return result;
}

determinePeopleForEachTripType(trip, travelers, 'car');
```

Expected result: Set contains [123, 456, 789]. But actual output is Set contains [123, 456]. What are some possible ways to fix this code?

Answer (score 1):

[`Set.prototype.add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add) only takes one argument, and that's the one element - you need to iterate through `travellers` and `add` each item separately:

```
item.travelers.forEach(Set.prototype.add, store);
```

Comment: But I thought the spread operator was already for that?

Comment: No, see the docs - unlike `push`, `add` only has one parameter, so can *only* add one item each time. That's why we need the loop.

Comment: I see. Could you help me understand why the Set then adds 123 and 456 when used with the spread operator?

Comment: you have a travelers array with first element 123, and another with first element 456 - so that's why - change the second array to `travelers: [789, 456]` to see that *your code* would add 123 and 789

Comment: You're doing the equivalent of `store.add(123, 456)` followed by `store.add(456, 789)`.  The first statement add `123` to the list, and ignores the `456` parameter.  The second adds `456` and ignores the `789` one, as `add` only cares about the first parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work, you'd need to use `item.travelers.forEach(Set.prototype.add, store)` to have the right context

Comment: Ok @Bergi, never to sure about these ones - I'll edit my answer. Is it due to the `this` context?

Comment: Yes, the `this` context of `add`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const travelers = [
  {
  id: 123,
  name: 'John'
  },
  {
  id: 456,
  name: 'Raymond'
  },
  {
  id: 789,
  name: 'Mary'
  },
];


const trip = [
  {
    type: 'car',
    travelers: [123, 456]
  },
  {
    type: 'flight',
    travelers: []
  },
  {
    type: 'car',
    travelers: [456, 789]
  },
];


function determinePeopleForEachTripType(arr, travelers, type){
  const result = [];
  let store = new Set();

  for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
    let item = arr[i];
    if(item.type === type){
      for (let traveler of item.travelers) {
        store.add(traveler);
      }
    }
  }

  store.forEach(eachStore =>{
    for(let j = 0; j< travelers.length; j++){
      if(eachStore === travelers[j].id){
        result.push(travelers[j].name)
      }
    }
  })

  return result;
}

const result = determinePeopleForEachTripType(trip, travelers, 'car');

console.log(result)
```